# vue-router how to persist navbar?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm learning Vue coming from React, and wondering what the correct way to persist a navbar is - i have navigation on there with router links.

I have a navbar component with router-links which works, but it is reloading when heading to another route. Is there a way to persist it "outside" of the body components? Such as it isn't re-rendered when heading to a new route?

I tried putting it outside the router-view, but it does not render anywhere:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <topnavbar>
    </topnavbar>
    <router-view>
    </router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Same if it goes inside.

How do I persist the navbar? Should it be the parent of all components that go into the router, or what is best practice?

Comment: Use the built-in abstract component `<keep-alive>`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your navbar should render outside the `router-view`, here's how to set it up (you may have done a lot of this already).

First, start with a base app that serves up all your routes:

**App.vue (Base App)**

```
<template>
  <topnavbar />
  <router-view />
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import topnavbar from './topnavbar.vue'
  export default{
    components:{
      topnavbar // register component
    }
  }

</script>
```

Now all you need to do is set up your router and mount the base App to your main Vue instance:

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from ''./components/App.vue // import the base component

Vue.use(VueRouter);

// import views you want to serve up in `router-view`
import Foo from './components/views/Foo.vue' 
import Bar from './components/views/Bar.vue' 

const routes = [{
    path: '/foo',
    component: Foo
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    component: Bar
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App), // mount the base component
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

That should set everything up. Now, in order to make sure that the navbar doesn't refresh make sure you use `router-link` and not anchor tags:

**Topnavbar.vue**

```
<div id="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><router-link to="foo">Foo</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="bar">Bar</router-link></li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

That should now serve up the components in your app without re-rendering `topnavbar` each time you navigate to a different page.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukoebmwo/

Comment: I'm confused, but fix it like you say in `main.js` doesn't seem to change anything :/ Also, my webpack configuration (which is the native one with vue's webpack-template) uses `vue/dist/vue.esm.js` (The full runtime+compiler version)

Comment: Can components outside of my router-view receive emit events? I did this, but my Navbar is not receiving emits to know when the user is logged in.