# Vuejs : "template or render function not defined" of a single-file-component

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to import all the components of a folder, and show one of them depending of a prop passed.

I use webpack with vue-loader to import all my components. Every component is a *.vue file.

The problem is that by importing some of my components stored in a subfolder, I got this error at runtime :

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Test2>
       <VoneDocs> at src\components\VoneDocs.vue
         <App> at src\App.vue
           <Root>
```

After reserach and the help of @craig_h I found that the problem come from the way I import my files :

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
  <div class="vone-docs" v-if="docName !== undefined">
    <component :is="docName"/>
  </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import Test from '../assets/docs/Test';

// import all docs (*.vue files) in '../assets/docs'
let docsContext = require.context('../assets/docs', false, /\.vue$/);
let docsData = {}; // docsData is {...<filenames>: <components data>}
let docsNames = {};
let docsComponents = {};
docsContext.keys().forEach(function (key) {
  docsData[key] = docsContext(key); // contains [{<filename>: <component data>}]
  docsNames[key] = key.replace(/^\.\/(.+)\.vue$/, '$1'); // contains [{<filename>: <component name>}]
  docsComponents[docsNames[key]] = docsData[key]; // contains [{<component name>: <component data>}]
});

export default {
  name: 'vone-docs',

  props: ['page'],

  components: {
    ...docsComponents,
    Test
  },

  computed: {
    docName () {
      return this.page;
    },

    docFileName () {
      return './' + this.docName + '.vue';
    },

    docData () {
      return docsData[this.docFileName];
    }
  },

  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    if (to.path === from.path) {
      location.hash = to.hash;
    } else next();
  },

  mounted () {
    console.log(docsComponents);
  }
};
</script>
```

While my `Test` component is successfully displayed when `docName` is `'test'` (because it's directly imported), every another Vue single-file-component imported with `require.context()` leads to the error : `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Is there anything I wrote wrong with my `require.context()` ?

Here is my webpack configuration (except the use of raw-loader and html-loader, it is the same as Vue webpack-template's one).

```
// webpack.base.conf.js
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint? [{
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
          emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
        }
      }] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      // Art SVG are loaded as strings. Must be placed in the html with `v-html` directive.
      {
        test: /\.raw\.svg$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
      // Icon SVG are loaded as files like regular images.
      {
        test: /\.icon\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs: [':data-src', 'img:src']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What does your main vue instance look like? Have you defined a render function?

Comment: I edited the post ! ;) I use only *.vue file which don't require render functions (as far i know), and a string-template in my main Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ah OK, if you're using the build without the template compiler, you cannot use the `template` property. What you need to do instead is mount your base component (the one with `router-view` in it) to your main view instance using a render function:

```
import App from './components/App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App) // This mounts the base component (App.vue) on to `#app`
})
```

Remember that your base component should also be a `.vue` file.

I wrote a fairly detailed answer on setting up a Vue SPA the other day which might help you out: [vue-router how to persist navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431867/vue-router-how-to-persist-navbar/47434176#47434176)

Comment: I'm confused, fix it like you say doesn't weem to change anything :/ By the way, in my Webpack configuration (which is Vue's webpack-template one), Vue as loaded as `'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'`, the full version (compiler+runtime)

Comment: Those templates work out of the box, so something else is wrong. It's going to be tough to know exactly where, but I would start by removing the `id="app"` from `App.vue` because that id will also be used in `index.html` which may be causing a conflicts.

Comment: Yes you're right ! I fixed this but it's not really what that brokes the docsComponents

Comment: I've tested things and I'm pretty sure the problem came from my `require.context()` block of code. I explained it in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally solved the problem.

In https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-loader-with-webpack-not-supporting-commonjs-require/15014/4, Linus Borg says that with vue-loader doesn't normalise exports.

```
let docsData = {};

function importAllDocs (r) {
  r.keys().forEach(function (key) {
    docsData[key.replace(/^\.\/(.+)\.vue$/, '$1')] = r(key).default;
  });
}

importAllDocs(require.context('../assets/docs', true, /\.vue$/));
```

Access `r(key).default` instead of `r(key)` solved the problem.